# find <div> in a reloaded HTML page and apply function to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page that lays out `div` components and every `div` component call a function and pass `this` as an object. The `div` looks like this:

```
<div id="pull-requests-view">
    <div class="green-header">This is the 1st title</div>
    # this is the div that will flash on double click
    <div class="green" ondblclick="flashAndMessage(this)" onclick="unblink(this)" id="tile0">
    <img class="profile-photo" src="someImageURL">
    <div class="pill-green">
    <a class="hypLink" href="UNIQUE_LINK_FOR_EACH_DIV" target="_blank">tag information</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's really happening here is that there are multiple divs like that with different `id`. When I click double click on the `div` its calls the `flashAndMessage()` with argument `this` which results in my `div` to blink and flash using JQuery `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

Details aside, the actual problem is that I have polling implemented that re-renders the HTML including all the `divs`. So basically the flashing and blinking is lost once the page updates.

I have tried global variables that store the `this` object before the page reloads and tries to pass the variables to jQuery `find()` function so that `flashAndMessage()` could be re-applied.

However it is not working for me. Here are my functions:

```
function unblink(selector) {
    $(selector).stop()
    $(selector).fadeIn({opacity: 1})
}

function blink(selector) {
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function () {
            blink(this);
        });
    });
}

function flashAndMessage(selector) {
    var pullReqURL = $(selector).find('.hypLink').attr('href')
    blinkList.push(selector) # this is where the `div` is stored before the page reloads
    blink(selector)
}
```

Note: The `blinkList` is a global array that is defined on top of everything else. I have a loop that runs after the divs are reloaded and I do see those divs that I stored in the list. However, when I iterate through that list and pass the obj to the `flashAndMessage()`, it does not work. It feels like the object is not the same when re-drawn or it loses some identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code snippet not work because of restrictions, but code is tested and functional.

```js
function unblink(selector) {
    $(selector).stop();
    $(selector).fadeIn({opacity: 1});
    sessionStorage.href = "";
}

function blink(selector) {
    $(selector).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow', function () {
            blink(this);
        });
    });
}

function flashAndMessage(selector) {
    sessionStorage.href = $(selector).find('.hypLink').attr('href');
    blink(selector);
}


if (sessionStorage.href) {
      flashAndMessage($("a[href='"+sessionStorage.href+"']").parent().parent());
}
```

```html
<div id="pull-requests-view">
    <div class="green-header">This is the 1st title</div>
    <div class="green" ondblclick="flashAndMessage(this)" onclick="unblink(this)" id="tile0">
        <img class="profile-photo" src="someImageURL">
        <div class="pill-green">
            <a class="hypLink" href="UNIQUE_LINK_FOR_EACH_DIV" target="_blank">tag information</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as I get time, but I do have another question in my mind. How do I use sessionStorage and the implementation you have if I have multiple divs and all of them could be flashed individually.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a parent to `<div id="pull-requests-view">` that is *not* getting reloaded with your polling code, you should use event delegation (and not inline event handlers).

```
<div id="parent-id-that-isnt-updated">
   <div id="pull-requests-view">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

You can attach your event listeners to the parent that doesn't update and have it only trigger when the clicked element matches the selector:

```
var $staticParent = $('#parent-id-that-isnt-updated');

$staticParent.on('dblclick', '.green', function() {
  flashAndMessage(this);
});

$staticParent.on('click', '.green', function() {
  unblink(this);
});
```